# Codename one how to design an inverted status badge

Tags: codenameone

I have one I have designed using CSS but it's in the normal text direction direction

```
Status-green{
    font-size: 2.1mm;
    font-style: italic;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 1mm;
    padding-left: 0.5mm;
    padding-right: 0.5mm;
}
```

[image]

that's what I want to do the "APPROVED" status budge, how can I make it , am using CSS

Comment: You mean the green banner on the left. Do you want help in layering it diagonally on top? This can be done with custom painting and layered layout not with CSS alone for Codename One

Comment: FYI without the diagonal effect you can see this: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/badging-arbitrary-components.html

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, I mean the green banner on the left, how can I use custom painting and layered layout to archive it, have not yet used painting in codename one so don't know how it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do that:

```
// this is the green label
Label green = new Label("Green Stuff") {
    private int actualHeight = 10;

    // we ask for more space so when we rotate the label it won't be clipped out
    @Override
    protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
        Dimension d = super.calcPreferredSize(); 

        // since we asked for more space the background will become a sqare
        // we don't want that so we save the "real" height here
        actualHeight = d.getHeight();
        d.setHeight(d.getWidth());
        return d;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // we rotate by 45 degrees in radians around the pivot point
        // which is the center of the component
        g.rotateRadians((float)(-Math.PI / 4.0), 
                getX() + getWidth() / 2, 
                getY() + getHeight() / 2);

        // we save the old color and set a background color then 
        // draw the background manually
        int c = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(0xff00);

        // we take extra space so the banner will stretch further
        g.fillRect(getX() - 50, 
                getY() + getHeight() / 2 - actualHeight / 2, 
                getWidth() + 100, actualHeight);

        // we let the label draw its content
        super.paint(g); 

        // restoring the graphics context to the original value
        g.setColor(c);
        g.resetAffine();
    }    
};

// we're drawing the background manually so we must make it transparent
green.getUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(0);

// we're layering the component on top of one another. The green
// label is positioned in the top left coordinate.
Container cnt = LayeredLayout.encloseIn(base,
        FlowLayout.encloseIn(green));
hi.add(cnt);

hi.show();
```

[image]

Comment: I was interested in that question and your answer. I tried your code and saw that it does exactly what it's supposed to do. A tutorial on this kind of thing would be interesting :)

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani me to I was impressed about Mr.Shai's code ..Thanks, Shai, I think to it should be included in the tutorial

Comment: Today Shai published the tutorial, with two small corrections to the code: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/diagonal-badging.html. Thank you Shai.

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani yah I saw the post immediately and I updated mine too. thanks,   That's great work..